# Tesseract training error: Bad box coordinates in boxfile string

Tags: tesseract, tesseract-5.x

I have prepared the following ground truth files:

```
../tesstrain/data/Chechen-ground-truth
|-- 1.box
|-- 1.gt.txt
|-- 1.png
|-- 10.box
|-- 10.gt.txt
|-- 10.png
|-- 11.box
|-- 11.gt.txt
|-- 11.png
|-- 12.box
|-- 12.gt.txt
|-- 12.png
```

The box files are based on WordStr, here is the content of the file `1.box` for example:

```
WordStr 65 61 1556 254  0   #НЕКЪАШ А
    65 61 1556 254  0
```

In the file `1.gt.txt` I then have the corresponding text:

```
НЕКЪАШ А
```

And here is the image:

[image]

Running the command `make training MODEL_NAME=Chechen START_MODEL=rus TESSDATA=../tesseract/tessdata`, gives me an Error:

```bash
set -x; \
tesseract "data/Chechen-ground-truth/1.png" data/Chechen-ground-truth/1 --psm 13 lstm.train
+ tesseract data/Chechen-ground-truth/1.png data/Chechen-ground-truth/1 --psm 13 lstm.train
Bad box coordinates in boxfile string!  65 61 1556 254  0
No block overlapping textline: НЕКЪАШ А
Failed to read pages from data/Chechen-ground-truth/1.png
Error during processing.
make: *** [Makefile:258: data/Chechen-ground-truth/1.lstmf] Error 1
```

Tesseract v5.3.0

Built from the source by following the instructions: https://youtu.be/veJt3U44yqc